# How to use if condition for laravel form in radio input field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

```
{!! Form::radio('display','Y',TRUE) !!} Yes
{!! Form::radio('display','N',FALSE) !!} No
```

How to implement the the true false use if condition in laravel 5.3
like general form bellow:

```
<input type="radio" name="display" value="Y" <?php if($display=='Y')echo checked ?> > Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="display" value="N" <?php if($display=='N')echo checked ?>> NO<br>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this for the input:

```
<input type="radio" name="display" value="Y" {{ $display == 'Y' ? 'checked' : '' }}> Yes<br>
```

And something like this for `Form::radio`:

```
{!! Form::radio('display', 'Y', $display == 'Y') !!}
```

Comment: how to use the larave form like: {!! Form::radio('display','Y',TRUE) !!} , the condition use for true or false only @alexey-mezenin

Comment: I thought you want the solution for the input. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help

  
Thanks i can solve the problem use one form for create and update: 
{!! Form::radio('display','Y',isset($display)?$display=='Y'?'tru‌​e' :false:null) !!} Yes 
{!! Form::radio('display','N',isset($display)?$display=='N'?'tru‌​e' :false:null) !!} No

Comment: If you want to use `isset()`, you should do this: `isset($display) && $display = 'Y'` instead of `isset($display)?$display=='Y'?'tru‌​‌​e' :false:null)` which will return `true` if `$display` exists and has `Y` as it's value and it will return `false` if it's not set or it's `N`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{ Form::radio('display', 'Y', $display == 'Y') }}
{{ Form::radio('display', 'N', $display == 'N') }}
```

HTML FORM:

```
<input type="radio" name="display" value="Y" {{ $display=='Y' : 'checked' : '' }} > Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="display" value="N" {{ $display=='N' : 'checked' : '' }} > NO<br>
```

Comment: how to use if or alternate any way

Comment: please use the laravel form with condition @ian-romie-ona

Comment: Thanks i can solve the problem use one form for create and update:
        {!! Form::radio('display','Y',isset($display)?$display=='Y'?'true' :false:null) !!} Yes
        {!! Form::radio('display','N',isset($display)?$display=='N'?'true' :false:null) !!} No